# Why is $root required here?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am just referring the tutorials from knockout.js:

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail

In the UI the markup is:

```
<!-- Folders -->
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
    <li data-bind="text: $data,
                   css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
                   click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
</ul>
```

and it's ViewModel is:

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    self.goToFolder = function(folder) { self.chosenFolderId(folder); };    
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

Can anybody tell me what is is $root and why is it required? If I remove it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`$root` refers to the top model in KnockoutJS hierarchy (the one you use in `.applyBindings`). In your case `WebmailViewModel` object is the `$root`.

It is required, because when you use `foreach` then inside the loop the context changes. Everything you want to fire here is associated to an element within a loop. Thus you need `$root` to use functions/fields defined outside of that context (in your case `chosenFolderId` is a method of `WebmailViewModel` object).

Comment: Your answer is helpful to me,+1

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to check out the [binding contexts](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) page.

> **$root**
>
> This is the main view model object in the root context, i.e., the
>   topmost parent context. It is equivalent to **$parents[$parents.length
>   - 1].**

Answer (score 0):

The `$root` context always refers to the top-level ViewModel, regardless of loops or other changes in scope. This allow us to access top-level methods for manipulating the ViewModel.

In your example `$data` represent to folder array values like 'Inbox', 'Archive','Sent' and 'spam'. But `$root` represent root functions of ViewModel like `chosenFolderId` and `goToFolder` .

See http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/knockout/bSKG240313-Understanding-Knockout-Binding-Context-Variable.html

I think this link examples will help you more.